# Rolling Prior13 months with Current Month Sales

Tags: sql-server

Within a SQL Server 2012 database, I have a table with two columns `customerid` and `date`. I am interested in getting by year-month, a count of customers that have purchased in current month but not in prior 13 months. The table is extremely large so something efficient would be highly appreciated. Results table is shown after the input data. In essence, it is a count of customers that purchased in current month but not in prior 13 months (by year and month).

---input table-----

```
declare @Sales as Table ( customerid Int, date Date );
insert into @Sales ( customerid, date) values
  ( 1, '01/01/2012' ),  
  ( 1, '04/01/2013' ),  
  ( 1, '01/01/2014' ),  
  ( 1, '01/01/2014' ),  
  ( 1, '04/06/2014' ),  
  ( 2, '04/01/2014' ),  
  ( 3, '01/03/2012' ),  
  ( 3, '01/03/2014' ),  
  ( 4, '01/04/2012' ),  
  ( 4, '04/04/2013' ),  
  ( 5, '02/01/2010' ),  
  ( 5, '02/01/2013' ),  
  ( 5, '04/01/2014' )      
    select  customerid, date
      from @Sales;
```

---desired results ----

yearmth     monthpurchasers monthpurchasernot13m
201002      1       1
201201      3       3
201302      1       1
201304      2       2
201401      2       1
201404      3       2
Thanks very much for looking at this!

Dev

Comment: Btw, all the customers in your sample table have purchased something in the past 13 months. So, as per your conditions, any query we make will return zero rows.

Comment: Borat,First of all thank you for looking at this and taking the time to provide a suggestion.

Comment: Borat - perhaps the questions wasn't clear. We do want past 13 months for each interval. Meaning in 2014-01 - how many customers purchased (which is already have) and of those how many did not have purchases in the last 13 months from 2014-01. Same idea for each of the month bands. That may be the reason your query doesn't give the results I was intending.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't provide the expected result, but I believe this is pretty close (at least logically):

```
;with g as (
    select customerid, year(date)*100 + month(date) as mon
    from @Sales 
    group by customerid, year(date)*100 + month(date) 
),
x as (
    select *,
        count(*) over(partition by customerid order by mon
            rows between 13 preceding and 1 preceding) as cnt
    from g
),
y as (
    select mon, count(*) as cnt from x
    where cnt = 0
    group by mon
)
select g.mon,
    count(distinct(g.customerid)) as monthpurchasers,
    isnull(y.cnt, 0) as cnt
from g
left join y on g.mon = y.mon
group by g.mon, y.cnt
order by g.mon
```

Comment: Dean,Thank you very very much! This is not only the correct solution, it is also "efficient". I've been trying to figure out how to use the over, partition, and preceding functions for my problems and this is a perfect example. Much appreciated. - Dev

Comment: I selected it as answer but after testing some more, it seems as if --for cases where a customerid has a purchase more than 13 months ago (for example in prior 23 months) but not in prior 13 months - then it would give the wrong answer. I am trying to figure out how one could also incorporate something like a dateadd function with month -13 condition.

Comment: If there's a problem, pls update the question with more relevant sample data.

Comment: Thank you! I updated the data with some cases where this would happen and also added in a results table. However, I can't figure how to put a tab between columns so the results table is a bit squeezed. Only customerid 1 has purchases in last 13 months for 2010404 and 201401. Other customerid's have purchases beyond 13 months in the various yr-mth intervals (which we don't want to count).

Comment: @dean - I used table instead of table variable. I get an error with this query `Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 8 Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'order'.`

Comment: With a minor replacement using a lag function instead of the preceding 13/1 - I was able to use your query to achieve desired results! Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Below query will produce what you are looking for. I am not sure how performance will be on a big table (how big is your table?) but it is pretty straight forward so I think it will be ok. I simply calculate the 13 months earlier on CTE to find my sale window. Than join to the Sales table within that window / customer id and grouping records based on the unmatched records. You don't actually need 2 CTE's here you can do the DATEADD(mm,-13,date) on the join part of the second CTE but I thought it might be more clear this way.

P.S. If you need to change the time frame from 13 months to something else all you have to change is the DATEADD(mm,-13,date) this simply substracts 13 months from the date value.

Hope this helps or at least leads to a better solution

```
;WITH PurchaseWindow AS (
select  customerid, date, DATEADD(mm,-13,date) minsaledate
FROM @Sales
), JoinBySaleWindow AS (
SELECT a.customerid, a.date,a.minsaledate,b.date earliersaledate
FROM PurchaseWindow a
    LEFT JOIN @sales b ON a.customerid =b.customerid 
        --Find the sales for the customer within the last 13 months of original sale
        AND b.date BETWEEN a.date AND a.minsaledate
)
SELECT DATEPART(yy,date) AS [year], DATEPART(mm, date) AS [month], COUNT(DISTINCT customerid) monthpurchases
FROM JoinBySaleWindow
--Exclude records where a sale within last 13 months occured
WHERE earliersaledate IS NULL
GROUP BY DATEPART(mm, date), DATEPART(yy,date)
```

Sorry about the typos they are fixed now.

Comment: Poaca - Thank you so much for providing this. I've been trying to implement your query - there are some typos - and I am not sophisticated enough to fix those in sql. It doesn't seem to work as is - but I'll continue to study it and see if I can figure it out. Thanks-Dev

Comment: Sorry about the typos. It is fixed now. I am glad this is helping you.

Comment: Thanks so much Poaca - that really helps! The query now outputs results but you will notice that the findings are identical to what I had by way of output. In others words, the exclusion doesn't seem to be happening for some reason. I think it's something minor. I'll continue to look closely at it to figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

Tell me if this query helps. It extracts all the rows which meet your condition into a Table variable. Then, I use your query and join to this table.

```
declare @startDate datetime
declare @todayDate datetime
declare @tbl_Custs as Table(customerid int)
set @startDate = '04/01/2014' -- mm/dd/yyyy
set @todayDate = GETDATE()
insert into @tbl_Custs
-- purchased only this month
select customerid
from Sales
where ([date] >= @startDate and [date] <= @todayDate)
and customerid NOT in 
(
-- purchased in past 13 months 
select distinct customerid 
from Sales 
where ([date] >= DATEADD(MONTH,-13,[date]) 
and [date] < @startDate)
) 
-- your query goes here
select year(date) as year
    ,month(date) as month
    ,count(distinct(c.customerid)) as monthpurchasers
from @tbl_Custs as c right join
Sales as s
on c.customerid = s.customerid
group by year(date) , month(date) 
order by year(date) , month(date)
```